# Convert years into date time pandas

Tags: datetime, pandas

If I have a list of integers (e.g. [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, ...]), and I have them set as a Pandas DataFrame index, how do I convert that index into a Datetime index, so when plotting the x-axis is not represented as [0, 1, 2, 3...] +2.006E3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a DatetimeIndex if you cast the integers as strings first, i.e.

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex([str(x) for x in [2005,2006,2007]])
```

will give you a DatetimeIndex with January 1 of each year.

Comment: This is surprising as pd.Timestamp('2014') is the current day (though this is changing in 0.15)!